# Exclude Form Control from Form Event

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, userform

In a form event, such as Before Update, On Dirty, On Change, etc., is there any way in the VBA to exclude a specific form control from a procedure?  For example, if you are setting a message to appear in the On Dirty part of a form, can you tell Access to ignore when one specific combobox is dirty and only show a message when anything else BUT that combobox is dirty?

Of course you can just set the On Dirty for every single form control individually to show a message EXCEPT that combobox, but that is a lot of work if you have many controls.  I was wondering if it's possible to just have an exclusion criteria in the form event code instead, to catch everything BUT the one control you're excluding.

Comment: Editing anything causes the record to become dirty. Would have to test every control's edit state to determine if that control was the only one causing record to be dirty. And what should happen? What does 'ignore' mean - not save the edit?

Comment: No, I just want a message to display when the user edits any combobox, text box, etc., except when they are using one specific combobox that is being used as list options to navigate to a specific record.

Comment: I just did a quick test. Turns out an UNBOUND control does not make form dirty. That combobox should be UNBOUND.

Comment: Hmm, ok, this could be a solution.  Question though.  This combobox provides a list of project numbers and currently is bound and set to display a column called "Project Number" from a Projects table.  When a user selects a number from the combobox, the table will then change records to that project number.

If I remove the control source for this combobox, how do I reproduce its functionality via VBA?

Comment: You said combobox is to "list options to navigate to a specific record", normally controls used for selecting filter/navigation criteria are UNBOUND, otherwise data in record is changed. The filter/navigation functionality will remain unchanged without ControlSource.

Comment: Great, this solved my problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A control with purpose of providing means to type/select filter/navigation criteria, not for data entry, should be UNBOUND. If it is BOUND, it will change data in record. An UNBOUND control does not cause form/record to become dirty (edit state) - it is 'ignored'. Do not set ControlSource property.